# Issue with columns/rows on small

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kfnh7h6/1/)

With medium and up I have a row with 4 columns. For small I have 2 rows of 2 columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">Grape</br>These are either white or red</div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">Pear</div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">Apple</div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">Plum</div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that with small sizes, when the text is long and goes to a new line, the columns do not stack properly, with one columns on the left and three on the right.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/swnpkcLu/
you will probably have specialzed class names and your sass mixin for the media query (i'm not so familiar with foundation) - but css works.

```
.small-6 {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #ddd;
}
.small-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:40.063em) {
    .small-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

for IE8 support though you will need extra class names instead of :nth-child selector

Comment: why the downgrade - something wrong with hat? maybe i misunderstood thw question?